# How to do intersection match between 2 DataFrames in Pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Assume exists 2 **DataFrames** `A` and `B` like following

`A`:

```
a A
b B
c C
```

`B`:

```
1 2
3 4
```

How to produce `C` **DataFrame** like

```
a  A  1 2
a  A  3 4
b  B  1 2
b  B  3 4
c  C  1 2
c  C  3 4
```

Is there some function in Pandas can do this operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First all values has to be unique in each `DataFrame`.

I think you need `product`:

```
from  itertools import product

A = pd.DataFrame({'a':list('abc')})
B = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2]})

C = pd.DataFrame(list(product(A['a'], B['a'])))
print (C)
   0  1
0  a  1
1  a  2
2  b  1
3  b  2
4  c  1
5  c  2
```

Pandas pure solutions with [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([A['a'], B['a']])

C = pd.DataFrame(mux.values.tolist())
print (C)
   0  1
0  a  1
1  a  2
2  b  1
3  b  2
4  c  1
5  c  2
```

```
C = mux.to_frame().reset_index(drop=True)
print (C)
   0  1
0  a  1
1  a  2
2  b  1
3  b  2
4  c  1
5  c  2
```

Solution with cross join with [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) and column filled by same scalars by [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
df = pd.merge(A.assign(tmp=1), B.assign(tmp=1), on='tmp').drop('tmp', 1)
df.columns = ['a','b']
print (df)
   a  b
0  a  1
1  a  2
2  b  1
3  b  2
4  c  1
5  c  2
```

EDIT:

```
A = pd.DataFrame({'a':list('abc'), 'b':list('ABC')})
B = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,3], 'c':[2,4]})

print (A)
   a  b
0  a  A
1  b  B
2  c  C

print (B)
   a  c
0  1  2
1  3  4

C = pd.merge(A.assign(tmp=1), B.assign(tmp=1), on='tmp').drop('tmp', 1)
C.columns = list('abcd')
print (C)
   a  b  c  d
0  a  A  1  2
1  a  A  3  4
2  b  B  1  2
3  b  B  3  4
4  c  C  1  2
5  c  C  3  4
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But what if each DataFrame has multi columns?

Comment: Hmmm, it depends what you need. Do you need all combination with all columns? Maybe the best create new question with desired output.

Comment: but if need combine only all rows from one df with all rows with another df, `cross join` solution should worjk perfectly.

Comment: I edit my question :-). Now I used your 3rd solution and it works fine, but if there are so many DataFrame need to be processed. Will it costs lots of time in assigning and droping?

Comment: Not sure if understand. Do you have many dataframes and need one big df with all combinations?

Comment: I have many DataFrames like A,B,C,D, etc. Then I have to do the operation respectively between AB, AC, AD, BC, BD, CD...

Comment: I understat more. the better here is create in first step for all dataframe tmp columns only once, then merge and last drop. Unfortunately for cross join is not anothr solution, only wih scalar helper column if need all combination.

Comment: Thanks! I used the method too!